# Does JSTL sql:query violate MVC principles?

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

Ideally, we separate the view, controller and model in MVC.

Views are usually JSPs, models are DAO java classes and controllers are Sevlets.

However, with JSTL sql:query, we put data functionality in JSP pages.

So, does this mean JSTL sql:query violates MVC? Is it recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it certainly does, says so right [on the box](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html):

> The JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases listed in Table 7-7 are designed for quick prototyping and simple applications. For production applications, database operations are normally encapsulated in JavaBeans components.

Comment: That does not say it violates MVC. It suggests that they believe you will want a Javabeans layer for a production application but that could be for any number of reasons.